# Is instigating a crime through careless choices of words a violation of Lifnei 'Iver?

Tags: halacha, reward-punishment, lashon-hara-slander, lifnei-iver, injury

I would like to look at the scope of *Lifnei 'Iver* -- the commandment to not put a stumbling block before the blind (Lev. 19:14). Specifically, I would like to know how one is punished for the sin -- does someone who causes another person to sin liable for that sin as if he did it himself?  Must the violator of *Lifnei 'Iver* have intended that a person sinned as a result of his suggestions?  And would a person be in violation of *Lifnei 'Iver* if he was causing somone to sin without being warned that his actions constituted the sin of *Lifnei 'Iver* for which he could be punished under Jewish law (e.g. restitution, fines, lashes, etc.)?  Is that answer different if the person is an expert in Jewish law?  If the words that sent the events in motion constituted loshon hara (gossip) or motzei shem ra (slanderous lies), does the speaker have any liability for the damage caused to the ones whom he influenced with his words?

To give these questions context, lets use a very possible hypothetical.  Rabbi tells his students that smart phones are a sin and no one should have one, and that it would be best for the world if all were destroyed.  Student 1 sees that his roommate owns a smart phone and destroys it on his own, thinking that this is what his rabbi would want.  Did the rabbi unintentionally violate *Lifnei 'Iver*? To what extent is the rabbi liable for his student's theft and destruction of his roommate's property?

Second hypothetical:  Rabbi tells congregation that Ploni-al-moni is an "evil man" and should be "taught a lesson."  Congregant hearing this takes it upon himself to beat up Ploni-al-moni and put him in the hospital.  Might the rabbi be liable for *Lifnei 'Iver* because he didn't also tell his congregants that he meant G-d should punish the sinner, and not them?

Comment: Punished...like lashes?

Comment: @DoubleAA -- yes, under Biblica/Rabbinic law.  I.e. If I say to you "J.R. should be shot," and you shoot J.R., that might be a clear conspiracy.  But if I'm only suggesting he be shot, and you take that as an order, is my liability the same as yours?

Comment: AFAIK there is no statutory punishment for violating lifnei iver even with witnesses and warning.

Comment: @doubleaa I didn't know any either, which is why I think that the punishment might be derivative (i.e. based on the sin you unintentionally caused).  Rabbi Gedaliah Anemer, zt'l, used to say that when the eruv was down and he saw people carrying on Shabbos (either out of ignorance that the eruv was down or ignorance about what to do if it was down), he said that their sins were on him.

Comment: You misunderstand me (or I wasn't clear). I don't think there is ever a statutory punishment. What God does to you after 120 years is likely based on how bad the sin was, but nothing happens to you here.

Comment: @DoubleAA That could be an acceptable answer IMHO, especially if there is a source.  E.g. does anyone say that lifnei 'iver be a cause of premature death at the hands of Hashem?

Comment: @msh210 I wanted those tags in because of the hypotheticals.  If one speaks loshon hara or motzei shem ra, and that actually causes someone else to harm another, as in a real case this week, then perhaps the instigator should be liable to the victim as well.

Comment: But the question is general, not about the hypos, right?

Comment: @msh210 Yes, but I edited it to include the question.

Comment: In the first example, Hefker Beith Din Hefker may apply, especially if it was an official rule in the yeshivah that they be banned.

Comment: Too broad? [15]